# Morris area chart jquery/php

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, morris.js

I have a problem with morris chart.
I tried many times and in many different ways to create a morris area chart from data situated in a **HTML** table but I failed.

This is the way that I used to extract data from table:

```
$('.tabella_dati').click(function () {

    var table = $("#datatbl tbody");
    var $data = table.find('tr').each(function (i, tr) {
        var righe = $('td', tr).map(function (i, td) {
            return $(td).text();
        });
        var $ciao = JSON.stringify(righe);            
        $.post('charts', {data: $ciao}, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }).text();
```

I tried with and without post method.
With post method I tried to create chart in **PHP** function in this way:

```
function morris() {
    $data = Input::get('data');
    echo '<script>Morris.Area({element: "morris-area-chart",'
    . 'data: '.$data.'}, xkey: '.$data.', ykeys: '.$data.')</script>';
```

`xkey` and `ykeys` are wrong, i know.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks.

So...this is the table
[image: Table]

```
function buildTable($arrFilled, $arrDates) {
    $mesi = array("1" => "January",
        "2" => "February",
        "3" => "March",
        "4" => "April",
        "5" => "May",
        "6" => "June",
        "7" => "July",
        "8" => "August",
        "9" => "September",
        "10" => "October",
        "11" => "November",
        "12" => "December");
    echo '<table id="datatbl" class="table">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<th class="text-center">Country</th>';
    foreach ($arrFilled as $k => $v) {
        $arr = explode("_", $k);
        echo '<th class="text-center">' . $mesi[$arr[1]] . "<br>" . $arr[0] . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    $i = 0;
    $countries = array_keys($arrDates);
    foreach ($countries as $c) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class = "text-center">' . $countries[$i] . '</td>';
        foreach ($arrFilled as $k => $v) {
            $valore = isset($arrDates[$c][$k]) ? $arrDates[$c][$k] : $v;
            if ($valore != 0) {
                echo '<td class="text-center" bgcolor="#ADD8E6">' . $valore . '</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td class="text-center">' . $valore . '</td>';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}

function table() {
    $mesi = Input::get('month');
    $array = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $mesi - 1; $i++) {
        $arrayMesi[$i] = $i;
        $array[date("Y_n", strtotime("-$arrayMesi[$i] month"))] = 0;
    }
    $countries = DB::table('countries')->get();
    $country_index = 0;
    $arrDates = [];
    foreach ($countries as $c) {
        $arrCountires[] = $c->country_name;
        $subscription = DB::table('subscription')->select('quantity', 'country_id', DB::raw('concat(year(date), "_" , month(date)) as meseAnno'))
                        ->where('country_id', '=', $c->country_id)
                        ->groupBy('meseAnno')->get();
        foreach ($subscription as $s) {
            $arrDates[$arrCountires[$country_index]][$s->meseAnno] = $s->quantity;
        }
        $country_index++;
    }
    return $this->buildTable($array, $arrDates);
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example table and perhaps set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry but i now i use another chart (highchart) that automatically retrieve the data from table. Anyway,I wish to know how to resolve the problem with morris

Comment: Can you put the markup into a JS fiddle so that i don't have to manually make the table please?